# Quote in Cgridview with DAO

Tags: php, yii

I migrate from previous application without major changes but in previous CGRIDVIEW I used 
$data[name] for attribute columns

```
  'columns'       => array(
    array(
      'header'      => 'idimm',
      'value'       => '$data[idimm]',
      'filter'      => false
      'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width:15px;text-align:right;padding-right:10px;')
    ),
```

now it give me an error

```
Use of undefined constant idimm - assumed 'idimm'
```

and I fix just with quote " $data["idimm"]

What do I miss and where is defined?

I changed server and php version, Is it or is a Yii affair?

current PHP version is 5.4
with previous 5.3 no error with with eval for $data[idimm]

yii is in both cases version 1.1.15

Comment: have you tried: `'$data->idimm'`?

Comment: by the way in grid view column config you might need whether `value` or `name` parameters.

Comment: I tried now just for replay and gives "Trying to get property of non-object" because dataprovider is DAO and return array, You are right value in sit example is not needed but was just an example I remove and question is still valid. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i've done it as an answer for your approval.

Comment: In new PHP version array without quotes teasted as constant. Try with @IgorSavinkin answer. It will definately works

Answer (score 0):

In CGridView column config you might need whether `value` or `name` parameters (i do not know where the docs are on this issue, but i've seen it in the Yii's error debuging info).

Just leave one of them and for `value` attribute you better use object access notation:

```
'value' => '$data->idimm',
```

Comment: thanks again but as I wrote in replay to your commet I'using DAO that return array not object and you are right value in this example is not needed but was just an example I remove and question is still valid. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @LucaMarletta, if DAO returns an array only then you may use: `'value' => '$data["idimm"]'`,